# How to convert SelectedListViewItemCollection to ListViewItemCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to write a simple routine to process a list of items in a ListView and be able to handle all the items or the selected ones only. I expected this to work:

```
private void PurgeListOfStudies(ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic)
{
    /// process items in the list...
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.Items);
```

or this

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.SelectedItems);
```

However, the two lists have different and unrelated types, `ListViewItemCollection` and  `SelectedListViewItemCollection` respectively.

I've tried changing the type of the parameter to `object`, `ICollection<ListViewItem>` and several other things. But since the types seem to be completely unrelated everything fails either at compile time or at runtime during a cast.

This all seems odd to me since these are obviously the same type in reality (a list of `ListViewItem`s).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the MSDN documentation.

- [ListViewItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx)
- [SelectedListViewItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedlistviewitemcollection.aspx)

As you can see, both classes implement the interfaces: [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx), [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx), and [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx).  You should be able to use any of those as a common interface.

Note these are *not* the Generic versions (i.e. IEnumerable<T>)).  You'll have to enumerate over the collection and manually cast them to your desired object type.

```
private void PurgeListOfStudies(IEnumerable items)
{
    foreach(MyType currentItem in items) //implicit casting to desired type
    {
        // process current item in the list...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did read MSDN - but was overlooking the non-generic collections. I tried several variations of generic collections. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate this answer a lot. I had been trying to cast to the generic type, so now I know my error.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make PurgeListOfStudies a little more type safe, you could make it take a parameter of type `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>` like so:

```
private void PurgeListOfStudies(IEnumerable<ListViewItem> items)
{
    /// process items in the list...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>());
```

or this:

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.SelectedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>());
```

The `OfType<ListViewItem>()` extension method turns a non-generic `IEnumerable` into the more type safe `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`.

Edit:
If you're annoyed by having to explicitly call `OfType<ListViewItem>()` you could add extension methods to ListView:

```
static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> SelectedListViewItems(this ListView listView)
    {
        return listView.SelectedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> ListViewItems(this ListView listView)
    {
        return listView.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>();
    }
}
```

and then call

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.ListViewItems());
```

or

```
PurgeListOfStudies(myStudiesPageCurrent.ListView.SelectedListViewItems());
```